# How to solve this question by writing code in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Consider the control system shown in Figure.
Determine the gain K and time constant T of the controller
Gc(s) such that the closed-loop poles are located at
s = -2+-[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV0R2.png)j2.

I have solved the question on pen-paper but dont know jhow to do it in MATLAB and write the code for it.[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynemg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the symbolic toolbox:

```
syms k t s

%Write denominators:
Dd = s^2 + 4*s+8;
Dk = s^2 + (2+k*t)*s +  k;

%get coeffs
c1 = coeffs(Dd)
c2 = coeffs(Dk,'s')

%solve
solve(c1==c2)
```

Use `doc <command>` to check the documentation of the commands used to get familiar with the toolbox.

**Edit:** Also, check these commands:
`poly(r)`,`numden(A)`,`simplify(expr)`, `fliplr(v)`.
With these, you can even create a program to create the denominator instead of manually writing it. And keep in mind, you can write a complex number as: `c = 5+3i`.